# Spacing under root for tall, unslanted letters

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I was reading The [TexBook](http://www.ctex.org/documents/shredder/src/texbook.pdf) and came to the following part on page 169:

> Besides these cases, you will occasionally encounter formulas in which
>   the symbols are bunched up too tightly, or where too much white space
>   appears, because of certain unlucky combinations of shapes. [...] Here are some examples of situations to look out for:
>
> ```
> $\sqrt{\,\log x}$
> ```
>
> The positive thin space in `$\sqrt{\,\log x}$` compensates for the fact
>   that `log x` begins with a tall, unslanted letter

However on page 163 Knuth uses `$\sqrt{{\rm Var}(X)}$`, where in my opinion the rule should apply as well.

Which variant should be used?

What about upright math fonts like [eulervm](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/fonts/eulervm/doc/latex/eulervm/eulervm.pdf)? Should I always write `$\sqrt{\,k}$`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's always a judgment question. You should note that “log” has a descender, so the square root sign will be lowered to try and cover it: compare lines 1 and 2 in the following example, but also line 3. For the case “Var(x)”, the parentheses already provide some more room and `\,` doesn't seem necessary.

```
\halign{#\hfil&\qquad#\hfil\cr
  No {\tt\string\,}&With {\tt\string\,}\cr
  $\sqrt{\log x}$&$\sqrt{\,\log x}$\cr
  $\sqrt{\mathop{\rm Var}x}$&$\sqrt{\,\mathop{\rm Var}x}$\cr
  $\sqrt{\mathop{\rm Var}y}$&$\sqrt{\,\mathop{\rm Var}y}$\cr
  $\sqrt{{\rm Var}(x)}$&$\sqrt{\,{\rm Var}(x)}$\cr
}

\bye
```

[image]

Here's the example with `eulervm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\begin{document}

$\sqrt{k}$ or $\sqrt{\,k}$

$\sqrt{l}$ or $\sqrt{\,l}$

$\sqrt{p}$ or $\sqrt{\,p}$

$\sqrt{K}$ or $\sqrt{\,K}$

$\sqrt{L}$ or $\sqrt{\,L}$

$\sqrt{P}$ or $\sqrt{\,P}$

\end{document}
```

Judge for yourself. In the “l” case, I'd probably also try `\sqrt{l\,}`

[image]